# Повторное использование нейронной сети

Tags: python, gui, нейронные-сети, pycharm, интерфейс

Создал нейронную сеть, которая распознает заболевания растений. Написал код для повторного использования сети. Вот он:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
import numpy as np
import pickle
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array

# summarize model
print("[INFO] Загрузка модели...")
model = load_model('cnn_vill.h5')
print("[INFO] Модель загружена...")

# Load labels
filename = 'plant_disease_label_transform.pkl'
image_labels = pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb'))

# Dimension of resized image
DEFAULT_IMAGE_SIZE = tuple((256, 256))

def convert_image_to_array(image_dir):
    try:
        image = cv2.imread(image_dir)
        if image is not None:
            image = cv2.resize(image, DEFAULT_IMAGE_SIZE)   
            return img_to_array(image)
        else:
            return np.array([])
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error : {e}")
        return None

def predict_disease(image_path):
    image_array = convert_image_to_array(image_path)
    np_image = np.array(image_array, dtype=np.float16) / 225.0
    np_image = np.expand_dims(np_image,0)
    plt.imshow(plt.imread(image_path))
    result = model.predict_classes(np_image)
    print((image_labels.classes_[result][0]))
    
image1= r'D:\PlantVillage\val\Potato___Early_blight\03b0d3c1-b5b0-48f4-98aa-f8904670290f___RS_Early.B 7051.JPG'
print("Изображение загружено:", image1)
predict_disease(image1)
img = mpimg.imread(image1)
imgplot = plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

Теперь хочу сделать графический итнерфейс. Для этого использую PySimpleGUI и PyCharm. Суть в том, чтобы загрузить изображение, присвоить значение изображения переменной image, передать image в функцию predict_disease, и вывести результат на в объект sg.Multiline. Я новичек в python и еще не разобрался в создании граф.интерфейса, посему использую найденый мною шаблон. Может кто-то помочь реализовать задумку? Вот что мне удалось сделать:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
import numpy as np
import pickle
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
import io
import os
import PySimpleGUI as sg
from PIL import Image

# Load model
model = load_model('cnn_villn.h5')
filename = 'plant_disease_label_transform.pkl'
image_labels = pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb'))

# Dimension of resized image
DEFAULT_IMAGE_SIZE = tuple((256, 256))

def convert_image_to_array(image_dir):
    try:
        image = cv2.imread(image_dir)
        if image is not None:
            image = cv2.resize(image, DEFAULT_IMAGE_SIZE)
            return img_to_array(image)
        else:
            return np.array([])
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error : {e}")
        return None

def predict_disease(image_path):
    image_array = convert_image_to_array(image_path)
    np_image = np.array(image_array, dtype=np.float16) / 225.0
    np_image = np.expand_dims(np_image ,0)
    plt.imshow(plt.imread(image_path))
    result = model.predict_classes(np_image)
    print((image_labels.classes_[result][0]))

file_types = [("JPEG (*.jpg)", "*.jpg"),
              ("All files (*.*)", "*.*")]
def main():
    layout = [
        [sg.Image(key="-IMAGE-")],
        [
            sg.Text("Image File"),
            sg.Input(size=(25, 1), key="-FILE-"),
            sg.FileBrowse(file_types=file_types),
            sg.Button("Load Image"),
        ],

        [sg.Multiline(size=(70, 1), enter_submits=False, key='-QUERY-', do_not_clear=False)],
    ]
    window = sg.Window("VillCNN", layout)
    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        if event == "Exit" or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
            break
        if event == "Load Image":
            filename = values["-FILE-"]
            if os.path.exists(filename):
                image = Image.open(values["-FILE-"])
                image.thumbnail((256, 256))
                bio = io.BytesIO()
                image.save(bio, format="PNG")
                window["-IMAGE-"].update(data=bio.getvalue())

    window.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Load model
model = load_model('cnn_villn.h5')
filename = 'plant_disease_label_transform.pkl'
image_labels = pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb'))

# Dimension of resized image
DEFAULT_IMAGE_SIZE = tuple((256, 256))

def convert_image_to_array(image_dir):
    try:
        image = cv2.imread(image_dir)
        if image is not None:
            image = cv2.resize(image, DEFAULT_IMAGE_SIZE)
            return img_to_array(image)
        else:
            return np.array([])
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error : {e}")
        return None

def predict_disease(image_path):
    image_array = convert_image_to_array(image_path)
    np_image = np.array(image_array, dtype=np.float16) / 225.0
    np_image = np.expand_dims(np_image ,0)
    plt.imshow(plt.imread(image_path))
    result = model.predict_classes(np_image)
    print((image_labels.classes_[result][0]))
    sg.popup('Діагноз', (image_labels.classes_[result][0]))

file_types = [("JPEG (*.jpg)", "*.jpg"),
              ("All files (*.*)", "*.*")]
def main():
    layout = [
        [sg.Image(key="-IMAGE-")],
        [
            sg.Text("Image File"),
            sg.Input(size=(25, 1), key="-FILE-"),
            sg.FileBrowse(file_types=file_types),
            sg.Button("Load Image"),
        ],


    ]
    window = sg.Window("VillCNN", layout)
    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        if event == "Exit" or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
            break
        if event == "Load Image":
            filename = values["-FILE-"]

            if os.path.exists(filename):
                image = Image.open(values["-FILE-"])
                image.thumbnail((256, 256))
                bio = io.BytesIO()
                image.save(bio, format="PNG")
                window["-IMAGE-"].update(data=bio.getvalue())
                predict_disease(values["-FILE-"])

    window.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]